# How to create bar and pie chart using titanium studio?

Tags: android, titanium, bar-chart, pie-chart

I'm very new to titanium, so my case is to create bar and pie chart using titanium studio for android device. Can anyone give me a start on how to create bar and pie chart? Can I just create the bar and pie chart using titanium only?

Comment: Consider making your question more effective and understandable

Answer (score 0):

Immanuel, Please take a look at the following links, it will help you on this

1. [Titanium and Charts](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/44251/titanium-and-charts)
2. [Titanium Android Chart](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/147139/titanium-android-chart)
3. [Rgraph Charts Library in Titanium Mobile](http://bobsims.tumblr.com/post/13836304720/rgraph-charts-library-in-titanium-mobile)
4. [How to Draw Pie Chart in Titanium for Android App](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148593/how-to-draw-pie-chart-in-titanium-for-android-app)

Comment: Thanks for the link but some i had already look through, but i am really new to titanium, cant really understand what the code is about..

Comment: Please read the Rgraph Charts Library in Titanium Mobile(link 3) carefully which includes the code

Comment: Anand, but i am asked to use only (javascript)Titanium studio to create the pie chart... it doesnt seem like Rgraph works in javascript..

Comment: @Emmanuel, PLease refer http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148593/how-to-draw-pie-chart-in-titanium-for-android-app